# Https Client fails with SSL Peer Shut down incorrectly

Tags: java, ssl, https

The code below is supposed to ignore all certificates:

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String... args) {

    System.out.println("Initiating... ");

    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
        new X509TrustManager() {     
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            } 
            public void checkClientTrusted( 
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                } 
            public void checkServerTrusted( 
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        } 
    }; 


     // Ignore differences between given hostname and certificate hostname
    HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
      public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) { return true; }
    };

    SSLContext sc = null;
    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    try {
        sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); 
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom()); 
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    } 
    // Now you can access an https URL without having the certificate in the truststore
    try { 
        URL url = new URL("https://localhost:30009/iPG/c2b/multione"); 
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        conn.setHostnameVerifier(hv);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }

        br.close(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}

}
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1002)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
at post.Application.main(Application.java:66)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
```

I don't understand why this is the case.

Comment: The remote host closed the connection.  It didn't fail because the requestor did not trust the remote host.  Possible that server and client do not support the same level of TLS?

Comment: Or maybe the target does not use SSL at all. Ir requires SNI. Or requires specific ciphers .... - there are many ways SSL can fail and certificate validation is only one - and this is the one you cared about. But, if the server closes the connection unexpectedly then it is not because the client does not like the certificate.